# PHP script cant connect to sql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want my script to connect to a database and insert a simple apikey into it. The problem is that the script inst connecting to the database. Im running this script on a xampp installation on my pc.

Script:

```
<?php
    $servername = "127.0.0.1";
    $username = "root@127.0.0.1";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "apikey";

    // Create a connection to the server
    $conn = new mysqli ($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check the connection to the server
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO APIkey (APIkey)
    VALUES ('John Doe')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " .$sql. "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Does anyone has an Idea what could be wrong with the script?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need the host on the user name

```
$username = "root";
```

Is all you need